# Auto poplating an infopath form field depending on the input of another dropdown field

Tags: infopath-rules, infopath-form, auto-populate

I am creating an infopath for a sharepoint list where there are two fields - Type of defect (TOD) and defect priority (DP). TOD is a dropdown control and DP is a text box. I want DP to populate certain value when the one of the value is been selected in TOD feild.

Can anyone please advice me how do I do this. Any assistance would be really appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to do that:

Here in the below example: **TOD** is a dropdown list column which has three choice values and **DP** is text type column - this will be updated based on dropdown column **TOD** selection.

Step1:

Select the **TOD** column

Step2:

Click on the manage rules from the ribbon.

Step3:

Add Rule from the rule section.

Step 4:

Add Rule condition - here I have selected if **TOD** column value is equal "**Type1**" you can select with your actual condition.

Step5:

Action as the set field value - select your "**DP**" column  then the set the value as per your need - for example, I have set "1"

Notes:

- The above for one  **TOD** column value condition - continue the same steps for other value in the **TOD** column.

[image: Based on dropdown selection set textbox value in Infopath form]

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. :)

Comment: I have a new query. Can you please help if you have any idea on it. Thank you.. :)

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280562/is-it-possible-to-trigger-an-email-using-microsoft-flow-when-a-date-in-a-field-o