# Is it possible to trigger an email using microsoft flow when a date in a field of a sharepoint list item is nearby?

Tags: sharepoint-list, power-automate, send-email

I want to build a flow to trigger an email when a date in one of the fields is nearing. I have a field named Payment due date. is it possible to trigger an email 2 days prior to the Payment due date. So that I don't miss the payment due date and payment is not delayed. I tried using schedule in power automate. but what should I use while giving the path to the sharepoint list and selecting the sharepoint, I think if I use "when an item is created/modified" it will only trigger when an item is created/modified.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hello Ganesh, No, it did not help. :( I am not sure what trigger should I use and while selecting the schedule  - it gives me two options - delay and delay until. Not sure which one to use.

Comment: In that case you can edit the original question and add the additional updates to same question. Or you can ask additional details on answer by adding comments.